# A weird space issue Python

Tags: python, mysql

I have nearly successfully made a query for MySQL via Python that shows the most frequent datasets given the brand. The problem I am having is when I try to run the `print row[1], row[2]` command, it returns productnum instead of the space I want like product num. I tried doing `print row[1], " ", row[2]` but it doesn't satisfy the test cases. Is there another way to get around this problem. I know this may not sound like an important question but it has been bugging me and it is this problem that is not passing the tests. The full code is below.

Comment: What are you outputting to?  Console?  Browser?  Something else?

Comment: Note: that isn't the exact code you're running, as the `for row in rows:` with an unindented `print row[1], row[2]` right under it would raise an IndentationError. Also, there wouldn't be any space in `WHERE brand = 'foo'GROUP BY`. Can you edit this to include exactly the code you're working with?

Comment: OH! Is your test using tab characters instead of spaces, maybe? In that case, you'd want to write something like `print "%s\t%s" % (row[1], row[2])` to insert a tab between the two fields instead of a single space.

Comment: No its a space but its not working with a string.

Comment: It is really irritating.

Comment: Grabbing at straws now . . . is the test checking against a known good?  Maybe the test requires line breaks of a different form (e.g. the test may be looking for \r\n, as opposed to Linux \n)?  I also think verifying it's a space and not a tab in the known good is a good idea.

Comment: Well I have edited my question to include one of the tests.

Comment: I see that, but that doesn't help with checking for non-printing characters . . . a \n or a \r\n will look the same on the screen, and a tab and a space could look the same too, especially after a copy and paste.  Like I asked previously, is the test checking against a known good?  How do you run the test, and how do you know your code fails against it?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by a known good, I run the test like the test in the question with triple commas around it with a:if __name__ == '__main__':
        from doctest import testmod
        testmod(verbose=True)

Comment: I don't know why it fails but I am looking at other alternatives than strings.

Comment: Is that a typo in `product` in the last line of `load_data`?

Comment: Yeah must of typed it with that. On real script there are no spelling errors.

Comment: Is there a reason you refuse to past the real script? Because without it, we're reduced to wild guessing. Do you have access to the testing code that validates your output against what it's supposed to be?

Comment: Well I rename everything because of the whole plagirism thing but I'll post the full thing if you want. It isn't however any different from what I have posted. I'll edit my question.

Comment: I've posted my entire script but I can't post the MySQL database because its two tables and is over 7000 rows each.

Comment: My best guess at this point is that the source file you're importing is from Windows, and has \r\n line endings.  Try changing the import to `LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'` and see if you pass the test then . . .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please don't create your SQL by concatenating strings. Pretend I'm an attacker and I call your function like:

```
inject = "'; SELECT name,cardnum FROM credit_cards; --"
most_popular(inject, 'LOL')
```

Your code will helpfully expand that to:

```
SELECT DISTINCT brand, product, COUNT(*) AS num FROM table1 WHERE brand = ''; SELECT * FROM credit_cards; --'" "GROUP BY product ORDER BY num desc, product asc LIMIT LOL
```

and now your customers are suing you. Always, *always* use parameterized queries instead of building queries yourself. Change that `cursor.execute()` like to look like:

```
 cursor.execute("SELECT DISTINCT brand, product, COUNT(*) AS num FROM table1 WHERE brand = %s GROUP BY product ORDER BY num desc, product asc LIMIT %s", (brands, num_frequency))
```

I've been writing DB libraries for years and the idea of trying to get this stuff right still terrifies me, mainly because the penalties for screwing it up are so severe. Let your database library do the hard work for you.

Comment: Just getting my head around it.

Comment: @Hayden I hear ya, but it's critically important to get that one thing right 100% of the time. As a bonus, it's actually easier. :-) The main reason that I brought it up is that so many SQL examples do things the wrong way, and then your boss is on the front page of the newspaper for all the wrong reasons. I want to help you not be that guy.

Comment: I tried inputting that last bit of code and I get an error: TypeError: must be string or read-only buffer, not long

Answer (score 1):

what about `print "%s %s" % (row[1], row[2])` (not sure if explicit casting is needed for the rows)

EDIT: or `print "{0} {1}".format(s, s2)` (the notation with `%` is a bit old-fashioned)

Comment: Can't have a string as a space as the tests aren't formatted like that.

Comment: @hayden this solution looks like it should work.  Can you verify what the test is checking for?  And are all the product names sanitized (e.g. do not contain not printing characters in the db?)

Comment: When I put in the strings they do look exactly the same but they do not pass. I'll quickly edit my question to show you's the test.